# simulator for abm-machine instructions (Getting wrong output)

Tags: c, stack, simulator, warren-abstract-machine

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 10000
#define varr 6

struct Stack
{
    int top;
    unsigned capacity;
    int *array;
};

struct Stack *createStack(unsigned capacity)
{
    struct Stack *stack = (struct Stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    stack->capacity = capacity;
    stack->top = -1;
    stack->array = (int *)malloc(stack->capacity * sizeof(int));
    return stack;
}

int isFull(struct Stack *stack)
{
    return stack->top == stack->capacity - 1;
}

int isEmpty(struct Stack *stack)
{
    return stack->top == -1;
}

void push(struct Stack *stack, int item)
{
    if (isFull(stack))
        return;
    stack->array[++stack->top] = item;
}

int pop(struct Stack *stack)
{
    if (isEmpty(stack))
        return INT_MIN;
    return stack->array[stack->top--];
}
int peek(struct Stack *stack)
{
    if (isEmpty(stack))
        return INT_MIN;
    return stack->array[stack->top];
}
int simulator(char newString[100][80], int p, int r, int var, int ctr, struct Stack *stack)
{

    if (newString[0][0] == 'p' && newString[0][1] == 'o' && newString[0][2] == 'p')
    {
        pop(stack);
    }

    else if (newString[0][0] == 's' && newString[0][1] == 'h' && newString[0][2] == 'o' && newString[0][3] == 'w')
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < ctr; i++)
        {
            printf("%s ", newString[i]);
        }
    }
    else if (newString[0][0] == 'p' && newString[0][1] == 'u' && newString[0][2] == 's' && newString[0][3] == 'h')
    {
        push(stack, atoi(newString[1]));
    }
    if (newString[0][0] == 'p' && newString[0][1] == 'r' && newString[0][2] == 'i' && newString[0][3] == 'n' && newString[0][4] == 't')
    {
        int val = peek(stack);
        printf("%d\n", val);
    }

    else if (newString[0][0] == 'd' && newString[0][1] == 'i' && newString[0][2] == 'v')
    {
        int value1 = pop(stack);
        int value2 = pop(stack);
        push(stack, value1);
        push(stack, value2);

        int division = value2 % value1;
        push(stack, division);
    }
    else if (newString[0][0] == '-')
    {
        int value1 = pop(stack);
        int value2 = pop(stack);
        push(stack, value1);
        push(stack, value2);

        int substraction = value1 - value2;
        push(stack, substraction);
    }
    else if (newString[0][0] == '+')
    {
        int value1 = pop(stack);
        int value2 = pop(stack);
        push(stack, value1);
        push(stack, value2);
        int addition = value1 + value2;
        push(stack, addition);
    }
    else if (newString[0][0] == '/')
    {
        int value1 = pop(stack);
        int value2 = pop(stack);
        push(stack, value1);
        push(stack, value2);

        int div = value2 / value1;
        push(stack, div);
    }
    else if (newString[0][0] == '<' && newString[0][1] == '>')
    {
        int value1 = pop(stack);
        int value2 = pop(stack);
        push(stack, value1);
        push(stack, value2);
        if (value1 == value2)
        {
            push(stack, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            push(stack, 1);
        }
    }
    else if (newString[0][0] == '<' && newString[0][1] == '=')
    {
        int value1 = pop(stack);
        int value2 = pop(stack);
        push(stack, value1);
        push(stack, value2);
        if (value2 <= value1)
        {
            push(stack, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            push(stack, 0);
        }
    }
    else if (newString[0][0] == '>' && newString[0][1] == '=')
    {
        int value1 = pop(stack);
        int value2 = pop(stack);
        push(stack, value1);
        push(stack, value2);
        if (value2 >= value1)
        {
            push(stack, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            push(stack, 0);
        }
    }
    else if (newString[0][0] == '<')
    {
        int value1 = pop(stack);
        int value2 = pop(stack);
        push(stack, value1);
        push(stack, value2);
        if (value2 < value1)
        {
            push(stack, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            push(stack, 0);
        }
    }
    else if (newString[0][0] == '>')
    {
        int value1 = pop(stack);
        int value2 = pop(stack);
        push(stack, value1);
        push(stack, value2);
        if (value2 > value1)
        {
            push(stack, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            push(stack, 0);
        }
    }

    else if (newString[0][0] == '=')
    {
        int value1 = pop(stack);
        int value2 = pop(stack);
        push(stack, value1);
        push(stack, value2);
        if (value2 == value1)
        {
            push(stack, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            push(stack, 0);
        }
    }

    else if (newString[0][0] == '&')
    {
        int value1 = pop(stack);
        int value2 = pop(stack);
        push(stack, value1);
        push(stack, value2);
        int value3 = value2 && value1;
        push(stack, value3);
    }
    else if (newString[0][0] == '|')
    {
        int value1 = pop(stack);
        int value2 = pop(stack);
        push(stack, value1);
        push(stack, value2);
        int value3 = value2 || value1;
        push(stack, value3);
    }
    else if (newString[0][0] == '!')
    {
        int value1 = pop(stack);
        push(stack, value1);
        push(stack, !value1);
    }
    else if (newString[0][0] == 'h' && newString[0][1] == 'a' && newString[0][2] == 'l' && newString[0][3] == 't')
    {
        return 0;
    }

    else if (newString[0][0] == 'c' && newString[0][1] == 'o' && newString[0][2] == 'p' && newString[0][3] == 'y')
    {
        int copy = peek(stack);
        push(stack, copy);
    }
}
int countspaces(char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH])
{
    int spaces = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= (strlen(line)); i++)
    {
        if (line[0] == ' ')
        {
            spaces = 1;
        }
        if (line[0] == ' ' && line[1] == ' ')
        {
            spaces = 2;
        }
        if (line[0] == ' ' && line[1] == ' ' && line[2] == ' ')
        {
            spaces = 3;
        }
        if (line[0] == ' ' && line[1] == ' ' && line[2] == ' ' && line[3] == ' ')
        {
            spaces = 4;
        }
    }
    return spaces;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *filePointer;
    FILE *filePointer2;
    FILE *filePointer3;
    FILE *filePointer4;

    int globalcount = 0;
    int tempP = 0;
    int tempR = 0;
    int tempVar = 0;

    int j, ctr, count, i, d = 0, z = 5;
    int p = 0, r = 0, var = 0;
    int arraylabel[varr];
    int arraylabelend[varr];
    char arrayLname[varr][20];

    char newString[100][80];

    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    struct Stack *stack = createStack(100);

    filePointer2 = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (NULL == filePointer2)
    {
        printf("file can't be opened \n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (argv[1][0] == 'd')
    {
        d = 1;
    }
    filePointer = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (NULL == filePointer)
    {
        printf("file can't be opened \n");
        return 0;
    }
    count = 0;
    int start, end, pCounter = 0, bstart, bend, bpCounter;
    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, filePointer2))
    {

        int spaces = countspaces(line);
        int order = 0;
        int t = 0;

        if (line[spaces] == 'l' && line[spaces + 1] == 'a' && line[spaces + 2] == 'b' && line[spaces + 3] == 'e' && line[spaces + 4] == 'l')
        {
            arraylabel[order] = count + 1;
            for (int s = 0; line[spaces + 6 + s] != '\0'; s++)
            {
                arrayLname[order][s] = line[spaces + 6 + s];
            }
            order++;

            if (line[spaces + 6] == 'f' && line[spaces + 7] == 'a' && line[spaces + 8] == 'c' && line[spaces + 9] == 't')
            {
                break;
            }
            if (line[spaces + 6] == 'b' && line[spaces + 7] == 'e')
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (line[spaces] == 'r' && line[spaces + 1] == 'e' && line[spaces + 2] == 't' && line[spaces + 3] == 'u' && line[spaces + 4] == 'r' && line[spaces + 5] == 'n')
        {
            arraylabelend[t] = count + 1;
            t++;
        }
        count++;
    }
    if (d == 1)
    {
        arraylabelend[0] = '0';
    }
    fclose(filePointer2);
    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, filePointer))
    {
        int begin = 0;
        int spaces = countspaces(line);
        j = 0;
        ctr = 0;
        for (i = spaces; i <= (strlen(line)); i++)
        {
            if ((line[i] == ' ' || line[i] == '\0'))
            {
                newString[ctr][j] = '\0';
                ctr++; // for next word
                j = 0; // for next word, init index to 0
            }
            else
            {
                newString[ctr][j] = line[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        if (!(globalcount >= arraylabel[0] - 1 && globalcount <= arraylabelend[0]))
        {
            simulator(newString, p, r, var, ctr, stack);
            if (newString[0][0] == 'l' && newString[0][1] == 'v' && newString[0][2] == 'a' && newString[0][3] == 'l' && newString[0][4] == 'u' && newString[0][5] == 'e')
            {
                if (begin = 1)
                {
                    if (newString[1][0] == 'p')
                    {
                        int *address = &tempP;
                        int add = (int)address;
                        push(stack, add);
                    }
                    if (newString[1][0] == 'r')
                    {
                        int *address = &tempR;
                        int add = (int)address;
                        push(stack, add);
                    }

                    if (newString[1][0] == 'v' && newString[1][1] == 'a' && newString[1][2] == 'r')
                    {
                        int *address = &tempVar;
                        int add = (int)address;
                        push(stack, add);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int *address = &tempVar;
                        int add = (int)address;
                        push(stack, add);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (newString[1][0] == 'p')
                    {
                        int *address = &p;
                        int add = (int)address;
                        push(stack, add);
                    }

                    if (newString[1][0] == 'r')
                    {
                        int *address = &r;
                        int add = (int)address;
                        push(stack, add);
                    }

                    if (newString[1][0] == 'v' && newString[1][1] == 'a' && newString[1][2] == 'r')
                    {
                        int *address = &var;
                        int add = (int)address;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int *address = &var;
                        int add = (int)address;
                        //  push(stack, add);
                    }
                }
                pCounter++;
            }
            else if (newString[0][0] == 'r' && newString[0][1] == 'v' && newString[0][2] == 'a' && newString[0][3] == 'l' && newString[0][4] == 'u' && newString[0][5] == 'e')
            {
                int ret = 'x';
                if (begin = 1)
                {
                    if (newString[1][0] == 'p')
                    {
                        push(stack, 0);
                    }

                    if (newString[1][0] == 'r')
                    {
                        push(stack, tempR);
                    }

                    if (newString[1][0] == 'v' && newString[1][1] == 'a' && newString[1][2] == 'r')
                    {
                        push(stack, tempVar);
                    }
                    if (newString[1][0] == 'r' && newString[1][1] == 'e' && newString[1][2] == 't')
                    {
                        push(stack, ret);
                    }
                    if (newString[1][0] == 'a')
                    {
                        push(stack, z);
                    }
                    if (newString[1][0] == 'f')
                    {
                        push(stack, ret);
                    }
                    if (newString[1][0] == 'f' && d == 1)
                    {
                        push(stack, varr);
                    }
                    if (newString[1][0] == 'x')
                    {
                        push(stack, begin);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // push(stack, tempVar);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (newString[1][0] == 'p')
                    {
                        push(stack, p);
                    }
                    if (newString[1][0] == 'r')
                    {
                        push(stack, r);
                    }
                    if (newString[1][0] == 'v' && newString[1][1] == 'a' && newString[1][2] == 'r')
                    {
                        push(stack, var);
                    }
                    if (newString[1][0] == 'f' && d == 1)
                    {
                        push(stack, varr);
                    }
                    if (newString[1][0] == 'x')
                    {
                        push(stack, begin);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        // push(stack, var);
                    }
                }
                pCounter++;
            }
            else if (newString[0][0] == ':' && newString[0][1] == '=')
            {
                int value3 = pop(stack);
                int adrs = pop(stack);
                int *ptr;
                ptr = adrs;
                *ptr = value3;
                push(stack, adrs);
                pCounter++;
            }
            else if ((newString[0][0] == 'b' && newString[0][1] == 'e' && newString[0][2] == 'g' && newString[0][3] == 'i' && newString[0][3] == 'n'))
            {
                begin = 1;
                pCounter++;
                continue;
            }
            else if ((newString[0][0] == 'e' && newString[0][1] == 'n' && newString[0][2] == 'd'))
            {
                begin = 0;
                pCounter++;
                continue;
            }

            if ((newString[0][0] == 'g' && newString[0][1] == 'o' && newString[0][2] == 't' && newString[0][3] == 'o') ||
                (newString[0][0] == 'g' && newString[0][1] == 'o' && newString[0][2] == 'f' && newString[0][3] == 'a' && newString[0][4] == 'l' && newString[0][5] == 's' && newString[0][6] == 'e') ||
                (newString[0][0] == 'g' && newString[0][1] == 'o' && newString[0][2] == 't' && newString[0][3] == 'r' && newString[0][4] == 'u' && newString[0][5] == 'e') ||
                (newString[0][0] == 'c' && newString[0][1] == 'a' && newString[0][2] == 'l' && newString[0][3] == 'l'))
            {
                int index = 0;
                for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
                {
                    if ((arrayLname[x][0] == newString[1][0]) && (arrayLname[x][1] == newString[1][1]))
                    {
                        index = x;
                    }
                }
                if (newString[0][0] == 'g' && newString[0][1] == 'o' && newString[0][2] == 'f' && newString[0][3] == 'a' && newString[0][4] == 'l' && newString[0][5] == 's' && newString[0][6] == 'e')

                {
                    int truefalse = pop(stack);
                    if (truefalse != 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                if (newString[0][0] == 'g' && newString[0][1] == 'o' && newString[0][2] == 't' && newString[0][3] == 'r' && newString[0][4] == 'u' && newString[0][5] == 'e')

                {
                    int truefalse = pop(stack);
                    if (truefalse != 1)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                char line1[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
                filePointer3 = fopen(argv[1], "r");

                if (NULL == filePointer3)
                {
                    printf("file can't be opened \n");
                    return 0;
                }
                int whilecount = 0;
                while (fgets(line1, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, filePointer3))
                {

                    int spaces1 = countspaces(line1);

                    int j, ctr1, i;
                    char newString1[100][80];

                    j = 0;
                    ctr1 = 0;
                    for (i = spaces1; i <= (strlen(line1)); i++)
                    {
                        if (line1[i] == ' ' || line1[i] == '\0')
                        {
                            newString1[ctr1][j] = '\0';
                            ctr1++; // for next word
                            j = 0;  // for next word, init index to 0
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            newString1[ctr1][j] = line1[i];

                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (whilecount >= arraylabel[0] && whilecount <= arraylabelend[0])
                    {
                        int pvar = 2;
                        int rval = 0;
                        simulator(newString1, p, r, var, ctr1, stack);
                        if (newString1[0][0] == 'l' && newString1[0][1] == 'v' && newString1[0][2] == 'a' && newString1[0][3] == 'l' && newString1[0][4] == 'u' && newString1[0][5] == 'e')
                        {
                            if (begin = 1)
                            {
                                if (newString[1][0] == 'p')
                                {
                                    int *address = &tempP;
                                    int add = (int)address;
                                }

                                if (newString[1][0] == 'r')
                                {
                                    int *address = &tempR;
                                    int add = (int)address;
                                }

                                if (newString[1][0] == 'v' && newString[1][1] == 'a' && newString[1][2] == 'r')
                                {
                                    int *address = &tempVar;
                                    int add = (int)address;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    int *address = &tempVar;
                                    int add = (int)address;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (newString1[1][0] == 'p')
                                {
                                    int *address = &p;
                                    int add = (int)address;
                                }

                                if (newString1[1][0] == 'r')
                                {
                                    int *address = &r;
                                    int add = (int)address;
                                }

                                if (newString1[1][0] == 'v' && newString1[1][1] == 'a' && newString1[1][2] == 'r')
                                {
                                    int *address = &var;
                                    int add = (int)address;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    int *address = &var;
                                    int add = (int)address;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (newString1[0][0] == 'r' && newString1[0][1] == 'v' && newString1[0][2] == 'a' && newString1[0][3] == 'l' && newString1[0][4] == 'u' && newString1[0][5] == 'e')
                        {

                            if (begin = 1)
                            {

                                if (newString1[1][0] == 'p')
                                {
                                    push(stack, pvar);
                                }

                                if (newString1[1][0] == 'r')
                                {
                                    push(stack, rval);
                                }

                                if (newString1[1][0] == 'v' && newString1[1][1] == 'a' && newString1[1][2] == 'r')
                                {
                                    push(stack, tempVar);
                                }
                                if (newString1[1][0] == 'f')
                                {
                                    push(stack, z);
                                }
                                if (newString1[1][0] == 'x')
                                {
                                    push(stack, rval);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // push(stack, 1);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (newString1[1][0] == 'p')
                                {
                                    push(stack, p);
                                }
                                if (newString1[1][0] == 'r')
                                {
                                    push(stack, r);
                                }
                                if (newString1[1][0] == 'v' && newString1[1][1] == 'a' && newString1[1][2] == 'r')
                                {
                                    push(stack, var);
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    // push(stack, tempVar);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else if (newString1[0][0] == ':' && newString1[0][1] == '=')
                        {
                            int value3 = pop(stack);
                            int adrs = pop(stack);
                            int *ptr;
                            ptr = adrs;
                            *ptr = value3;
                            push(stack, adrs);
                        }
                    }
                    whilecount++;
                }
            }
            else if (newString[0][0] == 'l' && newString[0][1] == 'a' && newString[0][2] == 'b' && newString[0][3] == 'e' && newString[0][4] == 'l')
            {
            }
            globalcount++;
        }
    }
    fclose(filePointer);

    return 0;
}
```

The Details
You are to develop a simulator for the abm abstract machine. Your simulator must support all
instructions included in the abm-instruction-set.doc document. You may refer to the abm program
files demo.abm, factProc.abm, foo.abm, operatorsTest.abm, and recursiveFactorial.abm to help
you to understand both the syntax and the semantics of the abm machine.

How to run the program?
•   gcc  hello.c -o abmsimulator
•   ./abmsimulator filename.abm

when I give it a operatorsTest.abm file it will show the output but - functionality doesn't work properly, like i am getting this ans:

```
5 - 4 = 1
 -1 //the ans must be 1
--------------------------------
 4 - 5 = -1
 1 //the ans must be -1
```

operatorTest.abm file

```
show  
show  This code illustrates basic arithmetic
show  and logical operations.
show
rvalue var
show Variables are initialized to "zero"
show Value of var is:
print 
pop    
show --------------------------------
push 5
push 4
show 5 - 4 = 1
-
print
pop
show --------------------------------
push 4
push 5
show 4 - 5 = -1
-
print
pop
show --------------------------------
push 5
push 4
show 5 div 4 = 1
div 
print
pop    
show --------------------------------
push 4
push 5
show 4 div 5 = 4
div
print
pop    
show --------------------------------
push 4
push 3
show 4 / 3 = 1
/
print 
pop    
show --------------------------------
push 3
push 4
show 3 / 4 = 0
/
print
pop    
show --------------------------------
push 0
push 1
show 0 & 1 = 0
&
print
pop   
show --------------------------------
push 0
push 1
show 0 | 1 = 1
|
print 
pop    
show --------------------------------
push 0
show !0 = 1
!
print
pop    
show --------------------------------
push 4
push 3
show 4 <> 3 = 1 
<>
print
pop    
show --------------------------------
push 3 
push 4
show 3 <= 4 = 1
<=
print 
pop
show --------------------------------
push 3
push 4
show 3 >= 4 = 0
>=
print
pop
show --------------------------------
push 3
push 4
show 3 < 4 = 1
<
print
pop
show --------------------------------
push 3
push 4
show 3 > 4 = 0 
>
print
pop
show -------------------------------
halt
```

file should be in same directory as the code file.

This is output i am getting

[image]

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Tip: `if ((str[0][0] == 'e' && str[0][1] == 'n' && str[0][2] == 'd'))` is equivalent to the readable `if(!memcmp( str[0], "end", 3 ))`. Apply this knowledge to your code and edit/update your question. No one wants to read 700 lines of code written as it currently is written..